# How To Correct Format Issue Exporting Data From One Google Spreadsheet To Another?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, export

**Script Source:** Coutesy of AJ Aviles

[Export Range of Data from One Google Spreadsheet to Another using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352388/export-range-of-data-from-one-google-spreadsheet-to-another-using-google-apps-sc)

**Issue:**
When exporting a range of data from one Google Spreadsheet to another Google Spreadsheet, missing data occurs because of an existing hyplink column.

**Goal:**
Need assistance refining the app script to only pull the values and not bring over the formula that exist.

[Sample Sheet (Sent To Archive)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vOS00pJd2YdQNC9KEFuGTm8tSO7Ez1M9SI41-nrwlwU/edit?usp=sharing)

[Sample Sheet (Recieve Data)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jNqtZB628GV8Y6fwvkdxTh7GVvQOwqvLdZRVZHIp_CQ/edit?usp=sharing)

```js
function archive() {
  const sss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vOS00pJd2YdQNC9KEFuGTm8tSO7Ez1M9SI41-nrwlwU');//src
  const ssh=sss.getSheetByName("Send Data");
  const tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1jNqtZB628GV8Y6fwvkdxTh7GVvQOwqvLdZRVZHIp_CQ');//tgt
  const tsh=tss.getSheetByName("Archive Here")
  const nsh=ssh.copyTo(tss);
  nsh.getRange("A2:Q50").copyTo(tsh.getRange("A1"));
  tss.deleteSheet(nsh);

  // This handles the Send Data sheet tab of the Parent sheet
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var sourceWorksheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var sourceData = sourceWorksheet.getRange("A2:Q50").activate();               // Gets data starting from A2 to Row Q and going down 30

  // This handles the Archive Here from the sheet tab in Parent Sheet
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  var targetWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
  var targetRange = targetWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceData.getNumRows(), sourceData.getNumColumns());
  
  var rowStart = 2;
  var columnStart = 1;
  var backgroundColor = "";
  var kitSelectRowStarts = 2;
  var kitSelectRowEnds = 15;

  sourceNumberOfColumns = 15;   // 30 Columns holding the Order Information
  sourceNumberOfRows = 50;      // 55 Rows holding the Order Information

  for(var i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j <= 52; j++){
      

      backgroundColor = sourceWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).getBackground();
      formula = sourceWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).getFormula();
      text = sourceWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).getValue();
      fontWeight = sourceWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).getFontWeight();
      fontSize = sourceWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).getFontSize();
      fontColor = sourceWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).getFontColor();
      textHorAlignment = sourceWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).getHorizontalAlignment();
      textVerAlignment = sourceWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).getVerticalAlignment();

      //Logger.log(wrap[0][0]);

      // Override and set background, font weight, wrap, etc.
      // targetWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).setBackground(backgroundColor)
      
      // WRAP only the Kit Rows
      if(i == 6 || i == 7){
        targetWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP);
      }
      else{
        targetWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j).setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.CLIP);
      }
      targetWorksheet.getRange(rowStart + i, columnStart + j)
        .setValue(text)
        .setFontWeight(fontWeight)
        .setFontSize(fontSize)
        .setFontColor(fontColor)
        .setHorizontalAlignment(textHorAlignment)
        .setVerticalAlignment(textVerAlignment);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the sheet by fixing the values.

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please set the source Spreadsheet ID, source sheet name, destination Spreadsheet ID and destination sheet name.

```js
function sample() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
  const srcSheetName = "Send Data"; // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID.
  const dstSheetName = "###"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  // Process at source Spreadsheet.
  const srcSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSpreadsheetId);
  const srcSheet = srcSS.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const temp1 = srcSheet.copyTo(srcSS);
  temp1.deleteRow(1);
  const range1 = temp1.getDataRange();
  range1.copyTo(range1, { contentsOnly: true });
  range1.clearDataValidations();

  // Process at destination Spreadsheet.
  const dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstSpreadsheetId);
  const dstSheet = dstSS.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const temp2 = temp1.copyTo(dstSS);
  const range2 = temp2.getDataRange();
  range2.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange("A1"));

  // Remove template sheets.
  srcSS.deleteSheet(temp1);
  dstSS.deleteSheet(temp2);
}
```

- In your showing script, it seems that the values, the background colors, the font styles, and so on are trying to be copied. In this case, I thought that the script might be a bit complicated. So, in this sample script, the sheet is copied as the fixed values. I thought that by this, the script might be a bit simple.

#### References:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo(destination, options) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

### Added:

About your following new question,

> I have a question about flexibility. If say, for whatever reason my data starts at B3 to S as an example. Is it as simple to create a variable to read it as "B3:S" or even "B2:S50" ? I see that in the script, you're removing Row 1 when making a temporary copy. That part makes sense to me, so would temp1.deleteRow(1); be adjusted to a value of any number and it would delete that many rows starting from the top?

> I would like some help on making a change to the script. I would like to tell it, what rowToStart , what columnToStart, and what columnToEnd, so that I can easily make a change to the script.

> A correction I need to make, I meant to just say rowToStart and columnToEnd.

First, the above sample script is for your 1st question. So, in your 2nd new question, it is required to modify the script. When your new sample Spreadsheet is used, the script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample2() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
  const srcSheetName = "Send Data"; // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID.
  const dstSheetName = "###"; // Please set the destination sheet name.
  const copyRange = "C4:H17"; // Please set the range you want to copy.

  // Process at source Spreadsheet.
  const srcSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSpreadsheetId);
  const srcSheet = srcSS.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const temp1 = srcSheet.copyTo(srcSS);
  const range1 = temp1.getDataRange();
  range1.copyTo(range1, { contentsOnly: true });

  // Process at destination Spreadsheet.
  const dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstSpreadsheetId);
  const dstSheet = dstSS.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const temp2 = temp1.copyTo(dstSS);
  const range2 = temp2.getRange(copyRange);
  range2.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange("A1"));

  // Remove template sheets.
  srcSS.deleteSheet(temp1);
  dstSS.deleteSheet(temp2);
}
```

- About `const copyRange = "C4:H17";`, this is from your new sample Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I have a question about flexibility. If say, for whatever reason my data starts at **B3** to **S** as an example. Is it as simple to create a variable to read it as "**B3:S**" or even "**B2:S50**" ? I see that in the script, you're removing Row 1 when making a temporary copy. That part makes sense to me, so would `temp1.deleteRow(1);` be adjusted to a value of any number and it would delete that many rows starting from the top? I left an example on my Sample Sheet called Smaller Sample for you.

Comment: @foragerEngineer About your new question of `I have a question about flexibility.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do about your new question. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: I would like some help on making a change to the script. I would like to tell it, what `rowToStart` , what `columnToStart`, and what `columnToEnd`, so that I can easily make a change to the script. Please let me know if this makes sense, and thank you for your help. Here is my sample sheet [Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vOS00pJd2YdQNC9KEFuGTm8tSO7Ez1M9SI41-nrwlwU/edit#gid=956835095)

Comment: A correction I need to make, I meant to just say `rowToStart` and `columnToEnd`.

Comment: @foragerEngineer Thank you for replying and adding more information. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that it is largely different from your 1st question. In your new question, do you want to copy "C4:H18"? And, do you want to keep the checkbox in the destination sheet?

Comment: @foragerEngineer About your new question, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand it, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? In this new sample script, the data validation is not cleared. So, the checkboxes are kept in the destination sheet.

Comment: Your `sample2` script is the best! It does exactly what I wanted it to do. It works fast and much to learn from it. Hopefully many people will find this one the most useful because it copies everything exactly the way as it should. Thanks again Tanaike!

Comment: @foragerEngineer Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issues were resolved. Thank you, too.