# How to format columns such that longer lines go to next row (Google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am merging multiple sheets into one. When I do sheet.appendRow, if the cell contains a sentence/line longer than the cell width, the cell just gets extended and covers up the next cell on the right destroying the orientation. I want it to go to the next line below in the same cell and keep the cell width fixed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the Developer Reference for wrapping lines: [Reference for WrapStrategy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/wrap-strategy)

Also, here is the reference that has methods for setting column width:
[Reference for Methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Finally, here is another Stack Overflow question were someone is using WrapStrategy for reference: [Export Range of Data from One Google Spreadsheet to Another using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352388/export-range-of-data-from-one-google-spreadsheet-to-another-using-google-apps-sc)

This should provide what you need!